# Email Addresses as Table Names, How to Use Prepared / "Safe" Statements?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

(Insert usual "I don't have a lot of hands on SQL experience" here.)

I've got a system that's responsible for sending out a fair amount of emails, and I'm adding functionality to save records of each email, segregated by the recipient.

Right now I'm setting it up so that these email logs will upsert a table with their email being the table name.  However right now, it looks like the `pg` library for Node.js doesn't allow using table names as part of the prepared statement.

My question is two fold, a) should I be concerned about injection when the able name will be based off of email address?  And b) if so, how can I get around security concerns here?

Example of how I'm handling this currently:

```
function _upsertTable(email, cb) {
  // Normalize email address.
  var tableName = 'email."' + email.toLowerCase() + '"';

  client.query([
    ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName),
      "(",
        "htmlMessage text,",
        "textMessage text,",
        "templateId character(24),",
        "files oid",
      ")"
  ].join(' '), cb);
}

// Insert email record into table
function _recordEmail(email, cb) {
  var tableName = 'email."' + email.toLowerCase() + '"';

  client.query([
    'INSERT INTO ' + tableName,
    'VALUES (',
      '$1,',
      '$2,',
      '$3,',
      'null',
    ')'
  ].join(' '), [html, text, templateId], cb);
}
```

### EDIT:

I would like to point out that this is a horrible idea in retrospect, and to urge others to not take this approach if they are considering doing the same.  Please read the comments to see why this would be a bad idea.

Comment: If you are really naming tables after email addresses then you should stop what you are doing immediately and learn about data modelling.  I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: @DanBracuk So I should stop what I'm doing and read a 600+ page book?  I don't see how this is a helpful comment, as this doesn't have anything to do with the question asked and doesn't provide anything useful for future readers.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica : you don't need to read a 600+ page book; only a few 3-line comments. I repeat Dan Bracuk: using email as a table name is a **very bad idea**. In your case: how would you ever retrieve all the users that use the same template(_id), or the files that they refer to? Maybe you'd have to use thousands of tables in one query (involving the catalogs) . In ... again ... : dynamic SQL.

Comment: @wildplasser Oh trust me after some thinking on the subject it was a *horrible idea,* and you bring up very valid points.  I just don't think that saying "read a book" is really all that great of a comment, especially if the line of logic is refuted with a couple of examples of why it's suboptimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepared statement parameter substitution generally only works for the data portions of a statement, not the places where SQL schema objects are referenced.

You can build this yourself with an adequate amount of escaping and quoting, but I suggest you don't.

A better way to restore the data your describing is all on one table with the email address being a column.  Possibly separate the email addresses into a separate table and point to them by integer ID to save some space.

Comment: Yeah, I felt as though if there isn't a way of preparing the statement then I was probably heading down the wrong path.  I'll go with a more basic way of saving these instead, probably storing all the email history in a single table.